# How I get SharePoint list from another site?

Tags: angularjs

I need to display list from my SharePoint site in the custom AngularJS site on another domain, but I don't know how to accomplish this.

Comment: Are you tried to use CSOM instead of angular.js ? or you must do it with angular.js

Comment: I want to use angular.js because I know it. I want to get some list from my sharepoint site to my angular site. thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SharePoint client object model (CSOM) to retrieve, update, and manage data in SharePoint 2013. SharePoint 2013 makes the CSOM available in several forms.

- .NET Framework redistributable assemblies
- JavaScript library
- REST/OData endpoints
- Windows Phone assemblies
- Silverlight redistributable assemblies.

**To Retrieve all SharePoint lists in a web in another farm using CSOM**

```
// Starting with ClientContext, the constructor requires a URL to the 
// server running SharePoint. 
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteUrl"); 

// The SharePoint web at the URL.
Web web = context.Web; 

// Retrieve all lists from the server. 
context.Load(web.Lists, 
             lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title, // For each list, retrieve Title and Id. 
                                    list => list.Id)); 

// Execute query. 
context.ExecuteQuery(); 

// Enumerate the web.Lists. 
foreach (List list in web.Lists) 
{ 
    label1.Text = label1.Text + ", " + list.Title; 
}
```

For more details about the sets of APIs available on the SharePoint 2013 platform, see [Choose the right API set in SharePoint 2013.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164060.aspx)

For Basic Operation using CSOM Check [Complete basic operations using SharePoint 2013 client library code.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912(v=office.15).aspx)